# How to dynamically call kotlin's object(singleton) method?

Tags: java, reflection, kotlin

I have a Kotlin singleton named `ApiService` like this:

```
object ApiService {
    private val someApi:SomeApi = SomeApi.create()
    fun getSomeApi():SomeApi{
        return someApi
    }
}
```

Now I want to call `ApiService.getSomeApi` dynamically.
I did something like this:

```
val fullClassName = "com.somepackage.ApiService"
val obj = Class.forName(fullClassName)
obj.getMethod("getSomeApi").invoke(obj)
```

But I got an error like:

```
Expected receiver of type com.somepackage.ApiService, but got java.lang.Class <com.somepackage.ApiService>
```

If I hardcode `.invoke(ApiService)` it will work fine, but is there a way to do this dynamically?

Answer (score 6):

A singleton method is still an instance method, so you need to pass the object instance to the method while invoking it:

```
val fullClassName = "com.somepackage.ApiService"
val cls = Class.forName(fullClassName)
val kotlinClass = cls.kotlin
cls.getMethod("getSomeApi").invoke(kotlinClass.objectInstance)
```

This is the same as any other instance method, except since you don't *have* the instance, because you're calling it reflectively, you need to retrieve the instance from the `KClass` using `objectInstance`:

> The instance of the object declaration, or `null` if this class is not an object declaration.
>   <sub>[kotlin.reflect.KClass.objectInstance](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/object-instance.html)</sub>

Since `KClass` has no equivalent to `Class.forName` (yet), you need to use `Class.forName` and then convert it to a `KClass` using `Class.kotlin`.

Comment: Thanks Moira,
It was very helpful and nice explanation :)